# pyinstaller will not compile with ico and noconsole

Tags: python-3.x

I have read the pyinstaller doc and over 30 different threads on this and have made countless attempts to create an exe with the exe using my ico for the exe file along with no console window being displayed.

I am running on windows 7 32bit and I am using the latest version of pyinstaller from PyPI and Python 3.6 (I have also tried compiling with 3.7), but nothing has working for me.  I compiles fine but When I execute the file after compiling to exe it does not use the ico for the exe image and it shows the console window along with my GUI.

I am using the following for the icon:

> icon="myimage.ico"

I am have tried the following for no console window using each command in separate attempts  while compiling:

> -w | --noconsole | --windowed

Full line used:

> pyinstaller --onedir --onefile –noconsole --name="NameYourFile" --icon="C:\Users\Home\Documents\pyfolder\iconName.ico" "C:\Users\Home\Documents\pyfolder\myFile.py"

Nothing I have done it working to have the exe use the icon as the image for the exe and I cannot prevent the console window from displaying.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Might not be the reason, but I once had problems with pyinstaller because I did not remove the old compiled folders dist and build before recompiling, did you do this, pyinstaller might not automatically overwrite.

Comment: I did delete all prior attempts prior to compiling.  I changed the directory it I had to placing the compiled file to back to python instead of my folder and everything is working properly now. I am now trying to remember the command to make it an exe, I think it is bdist but I am not sure... it's been awhile.

Comment: what do you mean with making it an exe? Doesn't pyinstaller output an exe?

Comment: yes... but to make it a distributable file. I don't recall if it is pyinstaller or perhaps cx_Freeze that uses the bdist to compile it into an installer file.

Comment: I believe that bdist is for cx_Freeze to compile it to an installer.

Comment: I found that compiling the code from the python directory worked best, problem resolved.